# How to serve static files from CDN after Heroku build?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku, cdn, nuxt.js

I have a small web application written in node.js and nuxt.js. The app is running on Heroku. I wan't to improve the speed of the page, however I have no idea which way would be the most practical to implement a CDN service.

The deployment flow is like: after pushing to Github I use auto deploy to Heroku. After deployment the node.js-buildpack generates the new build. I would like to host somewhere the static `.js` and `.css` files but I can't acces them on Heroku directly.

I was thinking on write a node function and simply upload the dist files after building every time onto my CDN provider.

I'm just curious wether a more simplier solution exist or not.
Thank you in advence.

Comment: You can use an add-on like Edge: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/edge I just started using it. All you need is to redirect the calls to the CDN domain you configure and you're done. If you don't want to use CORS in your Node server you can use the same domain name on both sides with a prefix on Node like api.[domain]